# PM2 to start multiple Node Applications with npm start on boot(using raspberry pi)

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, pm2

How can I run multiple nodejs applications using command npm start in different directories using pm2 on boot? Also how do i setup them to start again if any error occurs?

I figured out how to start npm start with pm2 using - "pm2 start npm -- start"
but I don't understand how to set up them to boot.

Based on my research "pm2 startup" gives the command to setup startup which I passed as it is in the terminal.

How do I set up the rest?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already got the part where pm2 automatically starts when you reboot, that's good.

You then need to add each of your apps to pm2.

Go into each of your project directories and run
`pm2 start your_file.js --name=my_app`, where `your_file.js` is the file you would use to start with regular node. (ie: `node server.js`, or `node index.js`, etc.) and `my_app` is a friendly name that you will see with `pm2 status` and can use to apply future commands to.

This should start your app. If you run `pm2 status` it is hopefully in the "running" state.

To save it so that it automatically gets booted when you reboot or restart pm2 you need to run `pm2 save` whenever you change app configurations.

You can do this for as many apps as you need to start.